# How to share an audio to social networks (Whatsapp, Facebook) in Android (2016)?

Tags: android, facebook, audio, whatsapp, sharing

I have developed an "app" which is a quite popular person from my country's  soundboard. It's very simple, it has 6 main buttons which play a different sound and then for each sound there are others 2 buttons, one for sharing the sound through social networks and another for setting the sound as ringtone, alarm or notification. At first, everything was working fine but one day, suddenly, it stopped working the function of sharing (the others functions are still working).

The message that appears is "The format is incompatible" for every single social network I tried to share (or something like that, it's in Spanish). You can download the app follow this link [download the app here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fzmobile.elgordodecentral&hl=es)

The last release code for sharing is the following:

```
            private void shareItAYQueNoEntren() {
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("audio/mpeg3");
                    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://fzmobile.elgordodecentral/raw/" + R.raw.yquenoentren);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share by..."));
                }
```

And the extension of the audio file in the raw folder is .mp3 .

How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: If the app didn't work in android 6.0 and above ,the issue is with the permission in manifest the android 6 and above you must provide runtime permission to read sd card

Comment: @SaravInfern Can you tell me which permission is, please?

Comment: please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "your audio file path here";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Also do not forget to add permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE otherwise you'll get an error while running your application.

Comment: I have tried your code with this:                                                               String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "android.resource://fzmobile.elgordodecentral/raw/" + R.raw.yquenoentren;                                                                            But it didn't work. It said that it couldn't attach an empty file...

Comment: your path is not correct "android.resource://fzmobile.elgordodecentral/raw/" : Do you want to upload file from RAW folder

Comment: for example :String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.mp3";

Answer (score 0):

Copy the audio file from the resource to external storage and then share it:

```
 InputStream inputStream;
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
 try {
inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound);
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

inputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

then

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));
intent.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound"));
```

Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to AndroidManifest.xml file:

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No problem, Any time

Comment: please make this question answered